# String in list is not changing after request | Python

Tags: python

I came here with a problem - the string is not changing after request.

That's my code:

```
row1 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")

position_str = str(position)
first = position_str[:1]
second = position_str[1]

first = int(first)-1
second = int(second)-1

if first == 1:
    map[second][1] = "X"
elif first == 2:
    map[second][2] = "X"
elif first == 3:
    map[second][3] = "X"

print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

And sure, when I type any number in between 21-23, 31-33 it's changing, but when I type 11, 12, or 13 it's not.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Lists are zero-indexed, which is why you subtracted 1 from `first` and `second`.  The rest of your code needs to follow suit and operate on the range from 0 to 2, not 1 to 3.

Comment: Thank you @Samwise for your reply.
The problem is, as soon as I change range to 0-2, X moves once to right, so for example when I type 33, it displays error 'Out of range'.
Could you please specify where should I change the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you translate the user's input from 1-3 to 0-2 here:

```
first = int(first)-1
second = int(second)-1
```

but in the remainder of your code you assume that the values are still from 1-3:

```
if first == 1:
    map[second][1] = "X"
elif first == 2:
    map[second][2] = "X"
elif first == 3:
    map[second][3] = "X"
```

Here's a fixed version of the code that uses consistent indexing and also eliminates a lot of the copying and pasting.  Note that naming a variable `map` is bad because it prevents you from using the very useful builtin `map` function!

```
treasure_map = [[" " for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
print("\n".join(map(str, treasure_map)))

position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")
x, y = (int(n) - 1 for n in position)

treasure_map[y][x] = "X"
print("\n".join(map(str, treasure_map)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two points.  First, lists are indexed from `0`.  So `map[0][0]` is the top left elements.  You can also just get rid of the `if` statements entirely.

Replace your `if/elif` statements with:

`map[first][second] = 'x'` and you're done.